# How do you check if a runtime instance conforms to some type using the Scala 2.10 reflection API?

Tags: scala, reflection

The following snippet returns true as expected:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
typeOf[Seq[Int]] <:< typeOf[Traversable[Int]]
```

This snippet does not however:

```
val s = Seq[Int](1,2,3)
val m = runtimeMirror(this.getClass.getClassLoader)
val t = m.reflect(s).symbol.typeSignature
t <:< typeOf[Seq[Int]]
```

I'm sure that I'm just missing something obvious, but I have been on the REPL for a couple of hours and haven't worked it out. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: parameterized types are erased because of type erasure. You can't get back the information that your seq contains integers at runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) `typeOf[...]` preserves the exact Scala type from Java erasure, however, `obj.getClass` (and consequently `m.reflect(obj)`, which uses `getClass` under the covers) does not. Consequently, the best runtime reflection can get from reflecting on `s` without extra compile-time efforts is `Seq[_]` (which will fail the subtyping test). If you need to remember the exact Scala type of something for runtime, use type tags (just like `typeOf` does) or macros (just like type tags do).

2) `.symbol.typeSignature` isn't going to work, because that's `ClassInfoType` (i.e. a type, which encapsulates a list of parents and members of a class type). Class info types work great for inspecting members (probably also for base classes and maybe for a few more things as well, but I'm not sure off the top of my head), but not so great for everything else. You'd want to go for something like `.symbol.asType.toType`, which would return a `TypeRef` (i.e. in our case `scala.collection.immutable.::` - note the lack of any type arguments here!). Unfortunately that'd still not work out of the box because of erasure as described in #1.

Comment: Thanks. Great description of what can / cannot be done with the Scala reflection library and why.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need reflection to ascertain that a given value conforms to a given statically known type. There are two ways (at least) to do so:

```
if (someValue.isInstanceOf[SomeType])
  ...
else
  ...
```

or

```
someValue match {
  case st: SomeType => ...
  case _ =>
}
```

Comment: this fails with `Seq[Int]` due to type erasure

Comment: Indeed, unless you request a `TypeTag` for the type parameter.